# csproj: Reference a dll file and Librarys

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, msbuild, nuget, csproj

Im new to csproj and msbuild and im trying to Build a small third Party PlugIn for Unity. The Problem is that the view Libs im using are not in Unity. So i have to build a separate PlugIn for Unity. Can somebody show me how to Reference a dll and a lib in csproj. The following Attributes im using are:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System.Threading" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Storage" />
<Reference Include="./bin/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also i tried PackageReference with Nuget. But at first i want to use the normal way to reference libs with csproj. Or do i have to use nuget? Don`t know. For the build i use Visual Studio Code with the specific PlugIns.

Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: Sometimes it helps VSCode figure out intellisense if you delete the unity generated csproj file and let unity generate it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dlls in your Unity project by putting them in the Assets/Plugins folder.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

If you want to have your code build to a separate dll, you can use assembly definition files.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html